# How is it possible to link to some named anchor?

Tags: support

I have frequently [long questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727535/razer-keyboard-use-keyboard-as-mouse-under-x) that I try to make shorter by populating footnotes.

Since this is rather uncomfortable for the reader to never stop scrolling forward and backward, I expected I could make use of named anchors and links to named anchors.
I tried something like :

```
Lorem ipsum and all that sort of things<br>
<a href="#NB1">Jump to Nota Bene1</a>
And could think of many other dolor<br>
Blah Blah<br>
<a name="NB1">Nota Bene 1 Start</a><br>
Nota Bene 1 Text
```

without any success. How is it achievable ?

---

EDIT 1 : Testing suboptimal workaround [<sup>1</sup>](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6036#:%7E:text=42653960361):

Just

Testing

The

Implementation

Of

A

Possible

Workaround

(**Obviously non functionnal**)

---

**1 :** 42653960361 : found this idea suggested in answer of some related question in meta_SE.
Caution : Its inventor qualifies it *"pretty fragile"*

Comment: I don't think I've seen such a thing; the closest I've seen are footnote numbers collected at the bottom and referred to by "sup" tags.

Comment: Unfortunely not, nor any good workaround even that I know of.  [Related MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349076/902710) along with [the original request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/902710).

Comment: It isn't. But if you feel it is necessary, I suspect that is a strong indication that you should just post shorter questions.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds : Too bad. But thanks for the links and you are correct, even the *"pretty fragile"* workaround suggested in the last answer of the original request just cannot fit the purpose.

Comment: You are dead right @terdon. However, the simplest the problem is in my mind, the shorter the question. And questions that I am likely to ask here relate to problems that are too complicated for my mind, this being most probably because… I have not even been able to word them simply… to myself at first... ;-)

Comment: I think your `#:~:text=` workaround is [not standard yet](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/) and isn't (fully) supported in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @muru , as usual you are correct. Nevermind it is far too laborious to implement.